# Header file C++

Tags: c++

when i'm trying to compile program but it says that i have an error in row when i'm to create a function pow(int base ,int exp),it says that 'pow': illegal qualified name in member declaration,here's my code:

Math.h:

```
#pragma once
static class Math {
public:
    static int Math::pow(int base,int exp);
};
```

Math.cpp:

```
#include "Math.h"
int Math::pow(int base, int exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line:

```
static int Math::pow(int base,int exp);
```

Does not need the `Math::` prefix since it is in the `Math` class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The class definition is probably intended to look like this:

```
class Math {
public:
    static int pow(int base,int exp);
};
```

`static` before the `class` has no meaning and is not allowed syntax.

The member function declaration doesn't need (and isn't allowed to) have a qualified name. It belongs to the class already because it is declared in the class scope. There is no need to qualify it any further.

---

From what you are doing it does seem however that you really want to have a namespace, not a class:

```
// Header file
namespace Math {
    int pow(int base,int exp);
}
```

```
// Source file
namespace Math {
    int pow(int base, int exp)
    {
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < exp; i++)
        {
             result = result * base;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```